# Duplicate rows x number of times based on linspace: np.linspace(RFMIn, RFMax, 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I figured out the series of element between RFMin and RFMax with using linspace, but now i want a Notation according to **RFRange = np.linspace(RFMIn, RFMax, 10)**. How should i do that?

**Notation, RFMin and  RFMax**

A100K 1000     3333
   B220K 5125.5    5888

```
import pandas as pd
Import numpy as np

df = csv.read_csv(filePath)
Notation = df['Notation']
RFRange = np.linspace(RFMIn, RFMax, 10)
RFRange = RFRange.transpose().flatten()
RFarray=[]
for i in RFRange:
       RFarray.append(i)
dict = {‘RFRange’: RFarray}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
data.to_csv(‘Output.csv’, header=True, sep=’\t’)
```

**I want something like this:

```
A100K 1000
A100K 1259.22
A100K 1518.44
A100K 1777.67
……..
…….
A100K 3333
B220K 5125.5
B220K 5210.22
B220K 5294.94
……..
…….
B220K 5888
```

Comment: Where are all those numbers coming from?

Comment: @DYZ From CSV File

Comment: I can see 1000 and 5125.5 in the CSV file. Where do all other numbers come from?

Comment: @DYZ other numbers comes from this line RFRange = np.linspace(RFMIn, RFMax, 10)

Comment: Make this information a part of your question. We should not read your code to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to extend `Notation` along with the `RFrange`.

try the code

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(filePath)
RFRange = np.zeros((df.shape[0],10))
for ndx, row in df.iterrows():
    RFRange[ndx] = np.linspace(row['RFMin'], row['RFMax'], 10)
RFarray=[]
Notation=[]
for ir, r1 in enumerate(RFRange):
    for i in r1:
       RFarray.append(i)
       Notation.append(df.loc[ir, 'Notation'])
dict = {'Notation': Notation, 'RFRange': RFarray}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
data.to_csv('Output.csv', header=True, sep='\t',
             index=False, float_format='%.2f')
```

Comment: @william I want RRange[ndx] = [1000, 1259.22, 1518.44, 1777.67, 2036.89, 2296.11, 2555.33, 2814.56, 3073.78, 3333.00]  Not repeating same ndx 10 times.